# Combine text fields for preview before submitting form

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been searching unsuccessfully for code to display the values entered into multiple text box fields combined on the page as the person types. I currently have 6 text boxes (description1, description2, description3, description4, description5, description6) that are combined on the backend with PHP to make a "final_description" that is then saved in the database. My goal is to have the user be able to see what the final_description will look like with all 6 fields combined before the form is saved and processed by PHP. The code I am looking for is very similar to what we have here on stackoverflow where when you type it adds it below so that you can see how it will output. I just want to have it where it combines multiple text boxes into one preview.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have:

```
<input class="desc" id="desc1" />
<input class="desc" id="desc1" />
<input class="desc" id="desc1" />
<input class="desc" id="desc1" />

<div id="final_desc" />
```

This would work:

```
window.onload = function(){
   function forEach(arr, fun){ return Array.prototype.forEach.call(arr, fun); };
   var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".desc");
   function updateFinalDesc(){
       var finalDesc = "";
       forEach(inputs, function(inp){ finalDesc += inp.value + "<br/>"; });
       document.getElementById('final_desc').innerHTML = final_desc;
   };
   forEach(inputs, function(input){
       input.addEventListener('keypress', updateFinalDesc);
       input.addEventListener('change', updateFinalDesc);
   });
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you use `knockout.js` data binding library here is how you can solve this:

```
<div id="content">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: description1" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: description2" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: description3" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: description4" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: description5" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: description6" />
    <span data-bind="value: combined"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.description1 = ko.observable("");
    self.description2 = ko.observable("");
    self.description3 = ko.observable("");
    self.description4 = ko.observable("");
    self.description5 = ko.observable("");
    self.description6 = ko.observable("");

    self.combined= ko.computed(function() {
    return self.description1() + " " + self.description2()+ " " + self.description3()+ " " + self.description4()+ " " + self.description5()+ " " + self.description6();
    }, self);
}

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel(), document.getElementById("content"));
</script>
```

Just make sure to include the `knockout.js` library in your page.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this. I know it probably isn't the best, but it seems to work:

```
var description1 = document.getElementById('description1');
var description2 = document.getElementById('description2');
var description3 = document.getElementById('description3');
var description4 = document.getElementById('description4');
var description5 = document.getElementById('description5');
var description6 = document.getElementById('description6');
description1.onkeyup = description1.onkeypress = function(){
document.getElementById('description1preview').innerHTML = this.value;
}
description2.onkeyup = description2.onkeypress = function(){
document.getElementById('description2preview').innerHTML = this.value;
}
description3.onkeyup = description3.onkeypress = function(){
document.getElementById('description3preview').innerHTML = this.value;
}
description4.onkeyup = description4.onkeypress = function(){
document.getElementById('description4preview').innerHTML = this.value;
}
description5.onkeyup = description5.onkeypress = function(){
document.getElementById('description5preview').innerHTML = this.value;
}
description6.onkeyup = description6.onkeypress = function(){
document.getElementById('description6preview').innerHTML = this.value;
}
```